# How to embed images dynamically into a table?

Tags: javascript, image

I've searched around a lot on this but haven't found an answer that works in my case. Hope someone can help.

I have a form and I'm looking to have images displayed dynamically within the form's table using Javascript.

For instance, in the code below:

```
<td class='ee122'>
<img src="images/cnn.JPG">
</td>
```

I need "cnn" replaced with a different value based on user input elsewhere on the form, and the replacement value is based on the following code:

```
<input value="" name="XLEW_5_3_6" id="XLEW_5_3_6" type="text" tabindex="-1"  
readonly="readonly" style='overflow:hidden; border:0px solid #000000;
 width:100% ' class='ee102'>
```

Can I incorporate this into the first code somehow, either by concatenating the input id or by other means? I just need to the images to be displayed dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: How is your image related to the html with the `input` field?

Comment: It isn't currently. That's what I'm trying to figure out - what's the best way to link the image with the input, and what code can be used to make the images load dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: Its still not very clear what you want to do, I'm not sure what you expect your output to be. Can you post what output you expect in your question?

Comment: Supposing the source of the default image is "images/cnn.JPG" as seen above. But I want other pictures to load in its place, say, "images/bbc.JPG" or "images/nbc.JPG", etc. What picture gets loaded depends on the value in the input shown above (ie. "XLEW_5_3_6"). So if XLEW_5_3_6 has a value of "images/bbc.JPG" then that image will load in place of cnn.JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it after tweaking the code a bit. Below is future reference for anyone with a similar issue:

```
function changeImage() {
document.getElementById('tableImage').setAttribute('src', document.formc.XLEW_5_3_6.value);
}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class='ee122'>
<img id="tableimage" src="images/cnn.JPG">
</td>
```

add id for the image

```
<input value="" name="XLEW_5_3_6" id="XLEW_5_3_6" type="text" tabindex="-1"  
readonly="readonly" style='overflow:hidden; border:0px solid #000000;
 width:100% ' class='ee102' onchange="changeImage()">
```

then create javascript function to change image

```
function changeImage(){
    document.getElemtnById('tableimage').setAttribute('src', document.getElemtnById('XLEW_5_3_6').getAttribute('value'));
}
```

or you can use jQuery for easier implement

```
$('#XLEW_5_3_6').change(function(){
    $('#tableimage').attr('src', $(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to using setAttribute and getAttribute? They seem to be still facing cross-browser issues.

Comment: I've also tried the code you posted but it doesn't seem to work.